# Is there a way to prevent exclusive horizontal/vertical panning/scrolling, i.e. railing?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, css

Testing on iOS, both Chrome and Safari browser apps are rather forceful in their handling of single-touch panning. A pan that starts primarily with either vertical or horizontal motion will remain stuck in exclusive vertical/horizontal motion for the duration of the pan. MS has CSS property: -ms-scroll-rails which can be set to 'none', however, there does not appear to be a more generic alternative for the rest of us.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was: no.

I ended up having to disable *all scrolling* and implement my own scrolling. This is no simple feat.